# PHP - Simple XML attributes problem

Tags: php, arrays, object, attributes, simplexml

I use PHP and Simple XML.

**I use a loop that does not work like expected:**

```
foreach($item->Image->attributes()->source as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value;
}
```

In the foreach I try to tell that I want to get the "source" of the image which is listed in the attributes.

`$item` above is created with a loop around my code above `foreach($xml_content->Section->Item as $item {}`, (if you need to know where it came from)

**My object looks like this:**

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#36 (4) {
    ["Text"]=>
        string(15) "Vinbergs socken"
    ["Description"]=>
        string(73) "Vinbergs socken ingick i Faurås härad och ligger i Falkenbergs kommun.
    "
    ["Url"]=>
        string(44) "http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinbergs_socken"
    ["Image"]=>
         object(SimpleXMLElement)#38 (1) {
             ["@attributes"]=>
                  array(3) {
                      ["source"]=>
                            string(113) "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/Faur%C3%A5s_Vinberg.svg/50px-Faur%C3%A5s_Vinberg.svg.png"
                      ["width"]=>
                          string(2) "50"
                      ["height"]=>
                            string(2) "41"
                      }
             }
     }
```

What is wrong with my loop in the beginning of my post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your are trying to iterate a string, not an array

```
$item->Image->attributes()->source
```

To iterate all the attributes of the Image element, use

```
foreach ($item->Image->attributes() as $attributeName => $attributeValue) {
```

If you just want to output the value of the source attribute, do not iterate but use the shorthand

```
echo $item->Image['source']
```

See this [demo](http://codepad.org/RvAn76oj) and the [SimpleXml Basic Usage Examples in the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)